# Symfony: How to make files public without moving to web-folder

Tags: symfony, web, include, twig

I have a JavaScript file inside a Symfony project that works with a few files within the "views"-folder in a Bundle. With assetic I include this JavaScript file. But now I have to make the files public the script needs to work with. In my JavaScript file I refer to a file inside public /somedir/ but of course my files will not be available for the script because they are only in the "views"-folder.

How can I make a file inside the folder "views" in a symfony project public, without moving it manually inside the web-folder? Notice that my question is not how to include files within Twig.

Or in other words: How to use Symfony assetic inside JavaScript files?

Answer (score 0):

Don't. Stick to [the recommended structure](http://symfony.com/doc/current/quick_tour/the_architecture.html#understanding-the-directory-structure), where public resources are located in `web/` directory. Refactor instead. Move the JavaScript file to `Resources/public/js/` directory and use [Assetic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/assetic/asset_management.html#including-javascript-files) to set it up.